# is it possible to combine a step monitor with a 3d contour plot

Tags: mathematical-optimization

```
ph = 80;
pc = 20;
kp = 0.5;
kc = 0.5;
kh = 0.778;
rt = 0.25;
rd = 0.1;
td = 10;
cfc = 10;
cfh = 10;
cobr0 = 68000;
ios0 = 75488.9;


c = {(120 - t1)*cfh == (t2 - 70)*cfc,
   fic == (t1 - 60)*cfh,
   fih == (140 - t2) + cfc,
   cobr == (pc*fic) + (ph*fih),
   ap == (cfh*(120 - t1))/(kp*(120 - t2)),
   ac == fic/(kc*dtc),
   ah == fih/(kh*dth),
   dtp == (((120 - t2)*(t1 - 70)*(((120 - t2) + (t1 - 70))/2)))^(1/3),
   dtc == (((t1 - 35)*40*(((t1 - 35) + 40)/2)))^(1/3),
   dth == ((40*(179 - t2)*((40 + 179 - t2)/2)))^(1/3), t1 >= 80, 
   t2 <= 110, dtp > 30, dtc > 30, dth > 30, ap >= 0, ah >= 0, ac >= 0};

ios = 6110*((ap + 0.00000001)^0.65 + (ac + 0.000000001)^0.65 + (ah + 
        0.000000001)^0.65);

pts = NMinimize[{ios, c}, {ap, ac, ah, dtc, dth, dtp, cobr, fih, fic, 
     t1, t2}, Method -> "NelderMead", 
    StepMonitor :> (Sow[{ac, ah, ap}])] // Reap;

ContourPlot3D[ios, {ac, 0, 2}, {ah, 0, 2}, {ap, 0, 2}, 
 Contours -> 10, 
 Epilog -> ({Red, PointSize[0.01], Line[pts[[2, 1]]], Yellow, 
    Point /@ pts[[2, 1]], Blue, PointSize[0.02], 
    Point[pts[[2, 1, 1]]]})]
```

So here is my problem. I can get the global optimum and i can create a 3d contour plot, but i can't figure out how to combine a step monitor with all of the above (or if it's even possible)

Comment: `Show[ContourPlot3D[ios, {ac, 0, 2}, {ah, 0, 2}, {ap, 0, 2}, 
  Contours -> 10], 
 Graphics3D@({Red, PointSize[0.01], Line[pts[[2, 1]]], Yellow, 
    Point /@ pts[[2, 1]], Blue, PointSize[0.02], 
    Point[pts[[2, 1, 1]]]})]`

Comment: This seems to do the trick. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only for this question not getting to the un-answered queue:

```
Show[ContourPlot3D[ios, {ac, 0, 2}, {ah, 0, 2}, {ap, 0, 2}, Contours -> 10],             
     Graphics3D@({Red, PointSize[0.01], Line[pts[[2, 1]]], Yellow, Point /@ pts[[2, 1]], 
     Blue, PointSize[0.02], Point[pts[[2, 1, 1]]]})]
```

Comment: i'm sorry i am a bit new here so i didn't know the protocol.

Comment: @user12073 You haven't done anything wrong. Welcome to the site. When you have doubts about the site etiquette you can ask in chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/wolfram-mathematica